# Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxContext is not supported because it implements IDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, telerik

```
private const int ItemsPerRequest = 10;
[WebMethod]
public RadComboBoxItemData[] GetAccount(object context)
{
    RadComboBoxContext obj = (RadComboBoxContext)context;
    DataTable data = GetDataAccount(obj.Text);

    RadComboBoxData comboData = new RadComboBoxData();
    int itemOffset = obj.NumberOfItems;
    int endOffset = Math.Min(itemOffset + ItemsPerRequest, data.Rows.Count);
    comboData.EndOfItems = endOffset == data.Rows.Count;

    List result = new List(endOffset - itemOffset);

    for (int i = itemOffset; i < endOffset; i++)
    {
        RadComboBoxItemData itemData = new RadComboBoxItemData();
        itemData.Value = data.Rows[i]["AccountLevelNo"].ToString();
        itemData.Text = data.Rows[i]["AccountDesc3"].ToString();
        itemData.Attributes.Add("Level6", data.Rows[i]["AccountDesc2"].ToString());
        itemData.Attributes.Add("Level1", data.Rows[i]["AccountDesc1"].ToString());

        result.Add(itemData);
    }

    comboData.Items = result.ToArray();
    // comboData.Message = GetStatusMessage(endOffset, data.Rows.Count);

    return comboData.Items.ToArray();
}

private static DataTable GetDataAccount(string text)
{
    int accCode = 0;
    string query = "select COA.LevelAccountNo,COA.AccountDesc as AccountDesc3,Level1.AccountDesc as AccountDesc1, Level2.AccountDesc as AccountDesc2 from COA COA,(select LevelAccountNo,AccountDesc " +
        "from COA where len(LevelAccountNo)=2)as Level1,(select LevelAccountNo,AccountDesc from COA where len(LevelAccountNo)=5)as Level2 " +
        "where Level1.LevelAccountNo=left(COA.LevelAccountNo,2)and Level2.LevelAccountNo=left(COA.LevelAccountNo,5) and len(COA.LevelAccountNo)>6";

    try
    {
        accCode = Convert.ToInt32(text);
        query = query + " COA.LevelAccountNo like '" + text + "%'";     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        query = query + " COA.AccountDesc3 like '%" + text + "%'"; 
    }

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    // string constr=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    // adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", text);

    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(data);
    con.Close();
    return data;
}
```

this is my web service code

```
 Collapse | Copy Code
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="cboAccount"  runat="server" Height="200" Width="200" EmptyMessage="Select an Account"
  EnableLoadOnDemand="true" ShowMoreResultsBox="true" EnableVirtualScrolling="true">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <h3>Accounts</h3>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ClientItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><span><b>Name:#= Text # </b></span></li>
                <li><span>Level6 #= Attributes.Level6 # </span></li>
                <li><span>Level1: #= Attributes.Level4 # </span></li>
                <li><span>Level4 #= Attributes.Level1 # </span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <br></br>
    </ClientItemTemplate>
    <WebServiceSettings Method="GetAccount" Path="InvestmentDropDownWebService.asmx" />
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

I am using for the first time webservice in my project. I don't know how to solve this error. If I am running `aspx.cs` this is perfectly running and values bind in combo box. But when I am binding values to combobox by using web service, its gives an error:

> The type Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxContext is not supported because it implements IDictionary.

Comment: Someone may be able to answer you but the best place for such question is Telerik forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue arise because of Visual Studio debugger. It's because of it's default behaviour. There's a workaround for that. Change your line

```
[WebMethod]
```

to

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

And also, Add an attribute of

```
WebServiceSettings-UseHttpGet="true"
```

in your ASPX code of RadCombo Box. 
See [this question in Telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/telerik-web-ui-radcomboboxcontext-is-not-supported-because-it-implements-idictionary) for more details regarding this issue

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is (xml)serialization.
Remember, the serialization-mechanism was built at the very start of the platform, nice things as generic-collections/dictionaries were added after.
This means that functionality that you would expect to work now, may not have been possible during the initial development.

Which brings us to the dictionary.
The base class of the dictionary does not support serialization, because the serializer does not like/handle 'unknown' types very much. Since dictionaries could be '[object, object]', it is unknown-type heaven.

An interesting way to create a similar unknown type problem is as follows.

1. Create a webservice that expects class 'a' as a parameter.
2. Create a web-reference to the service.
3. Create class 'b' that derives from 'a'.
4. Now call the webmethod with an instance of 'b' as a parameter

You will now get an error message saying that the call failed because 'type b was unexpected'. I hope you can see how these two things (unexpected type/dictionary) are related...

**You can only give an xml serializer the types it was told to expect at design-time**

The solution of 'sohaiby' will work because he is telling the webservice NOT to use xml-serialization, but to use JSON in the line:

```
ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json
```

This all being said, this is really Telerics fault and they should fix it.